# How to create a regular expression to add extra html tags to specific elements?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I am working on a Wordpress theme and in that the requirement is something like this.

1. While printing the page content, add DIV wrappers `<div class="image-wrapper">` to all the images. Which I have done.
2. While printing the page content, add DIV wrapper to other text except image a DIV wrapper `<div class="text-wrapper">`

The purpose of doing this is that I want to apply a styles so that all the text except images will have left and right margins.

The filter I have created for adding wrapper over images is like this

```
// Remove P Tags from image
function filter_ptags_on_images($content){
   return preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');

// Wrap images with DIV
function filter_images($content){
    return preg_replace('/<img (.*) \/>\s*/iU', '<span class="the-image"><img \1 /></span>', $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_images');
```

But I am not sure how to do the 2nd task which is to add DIV wrapper to rest of the content.

Comment: Are you generating the content also?

Comment: The content is added by clients from Admin panel